# How to specify Vary: Accept-Encoding header for an Angular application?

Tags: angular

How to add the `Vary: Accept-Encoding` header for an Angular application?

Comment: I think problem remains at your server side, what server you are using ? either its CORS settings or some other server side issue.

Comment: Am using the angular universal server with expressjs

Answer (score 0):

You add headers to HTTP requests by creating an instance of [`HttpHeaders`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) and passing that into apporpiate argument of the appropriate method in [the `HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#httpclient) instance that you can inject.

Comment: I have used the httpclient for http requests, can you send the sample code for this

Answer (score 0):

Good question, but i think its not in the scope of angular.
This should be done in the scope of the server the serves the static content.

If its ngiNx it is very simple configuration inside /etc/nginx/nginx.conf just add:

```
gzip_vary on
```

If you're serving from apache add the following code to your .htaccess file:

```js
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

(*) I suggest to add more tags to this question.